# Columns gone missing after using pandas pd.concat

Tags: python, pandas

I try to combine two data frames using the following code:

```
df1=pd.read_csv('NBA_2010_new.csv',encoding='ISO-8859-1')
df2=pd.read_csv('NBA_2011.csv',encoding='ISO-8859-1')
frames = [df1,df2]
combine = pd.concat(frames,axis=0,ignore_index=True,join='inner')
df=combine.reset_index(drop = True)
df.index += 1
```

The CSV files originally contains 26 columns..but the when i try to view df using df.info()...it only says 22 columns, some columns are missing....

Comment: Both CSVs have the same amount of columns? Are all the names of the columns the same in each? I see you have join = “inner” which would cause unmatched columns to disappear. Default value is “outer”

Comment: thanks...I check my csv files and there are column names that is mismatched that causes the problem...